# How to put postcss-calc to false in Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I need to set `postcss-calc` to `false` in a project (Sage 10 on Wordpress) that uses Laravel Mix.
This is my code but it doesn't work and it get no error:

```
mix
  .sass('resources/styles/app.scss', 'styles')
  .sass('resources/styles/editor.scss', 'styles')
  .options({
    postCss: [
      require('cssnano')({
        preset: ['default', {discardComments: {removeAll: true}, calc: false}],
      }),
    ],
    processCssUrls: false,
  });
```

The option I'm talking is `calc: false` as a cssnano option that use the dependency `postcss-calc`

Otherwise I can remove `postcss-calc` at all?

Any help please?